Certbot generated SSL Certificate not responding on Tomee9(Tomcat10)
I need to install my Java Web Application on Tomee9(Tomcat 10). For SSL my obvious choice is Certbot. I generated the SSL artifacts by following the instructions here:
https://medium.com/@raupach/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-tomcat-3db8a469e3d2
And the instructions worked well as expected:

Moved the artifacts to the conf folder

Next, configuration of the artifacts in server.xml:

But when I ran the Server, the response on the Browser is not encouraging:

Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Singhm

Not programming or development, but read the first sentence of the relevant documentation section -- which is also correct in the webpage you link, although that doesn't obey the second sentence

I tried after setting scheme="https" and secure ="true" - but unfortunately same error!

scheme and secure only matter to the app code and filters. Did you set SSLEnabled=true per the first sentence I referred you to?
